# App Crashes on Android 6 because module has text relocations

Tags: javascript, android, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

This is the error I got using adb logcat:

> W V8Object: (KrollRuntimeThread) [33,34] Runtime disposed, cannot set property 'userAgent'
>   E linker  : /data/app/com.app.id/lib/arm/module.id: has text relocations

I'm having this error when try to run my Titanium app on Android 6 device. As far as I know, this is something related to the NDK and my modules.
My problem is that I'm using around 5 or 6 modules on my app and I'm not able to recompile all of them. So, what can I do?

I also check this ticket:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19369

and also these issues on some modules repositories:

https://github.com/manumaticx/TiCrouton/issues/8

https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.inappbilling/issues/14

My environment:

Ti SDK 5.1.2.GA

Android 6.0.1 on Nexus

My Android SDK:
[image]

**important:** it doesn't happen on any simulator

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, you'll have to re-compile the problematic modules with the latest Android NDK, or find other replacements.

Comment: Download 10e, the latest version and then use 5.2.0.GA SDK (latest Appcelerator SDK) to update your application.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the comments. Soumya, I don't need to recompile the modules with the latest Android and Ti SDK?

Comment: Does the error actually block your app from running or are you just concerned about the error? I have seen it from time to time as well, but the app still worked.

Comment: Yes, it does crash my app =/

Comment: Yes, you need to use atleast Android API-21 and Ti SDK 5.2.0.GA to perform the build using Android NDK 10e.